# limit task to run once when conditions are met

Tags: c#

I have a schedule task that I need to launch when VPN connection return True. my code below schedtask run at least twice. any idea on how to limit this task to only run once ?

```
 public void AddressChangedCallback(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckForVPNInterface();     
    }
    public bool CheckForVPNInterface()
        {
            if (NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable())
            {
                NetworkInterface[] interfaces =  NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
                foreach (NetworkInterface Interface in interfaces)
                { 
                    if ((Interface.Description.Contains("Cisco")) && (Interface.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up))
                    {
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    schedTask();
                    
                    return true;
                }
              }    
        }
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: Check if function `AddressChangedCallback` is invoked more than once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your problem is there is more than one interface that satisfies those requirements

```
if (!NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable()) return false;

var runTask = NetworkInterface
   .GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
   .Any(x => x.Description.Contains("Cisco") 
             && x.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up);

if (runTask)
   schedTask();

return runTask;
```

If your problem is the event may fire more than once. A thread safe way might be to use [`Interlocked.Increment`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked.increment?view=net-5.0)

> Increments a specified variable and stores the result, as an atomic
> operation

```
public static int runCount = 0;

...


if (!NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable() ) return false;

var runTask = NetworkInterface
   .GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
   .Any(x => x.Description.Contains("Cisco") 
             && x.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up);

if (runTask && Interlocked.Increment(ref runCount) == 1)
{
   schedTask();
   return true;
}
```

Comment: thanks for this but the Interlocked variable would prevent the AddressChangedCallback. event from been called again if the user decided to reconnect to VPN

Comment: the Interlock actual worked once the runcount get resetted.